# Creating Login with Java, won't go to else statement?

Tags: java, arrays, authentication

I'm making a login program, but it is getting some errors. If I put in a name that is not in the list, I get an error. It doesn't seem to reach the `else` statement also, and I'm not sure why.

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String userName;
    int n = 10;
    int i = 0;

    String[] array = new String[n];
    array[0] = "John";
    array[1] = "Johny";
    array[2] = "ben";


    System.out.println("Enter your user name(Note:**Case Sensative**)");
    userName = input.nextLine();

    while (i <= array.length) {
      if (array[i].equals(userName)) {
        System.out.println("Your UserName is valid");
        break;
      }
      else if (!array[i].equals(userName)){
        i++;
      }
      else {
          System.out.println("Your UserName is not valid");
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary imports, the only one you need it `java.util.Scanner`, the others can be deleted. :)

Answer (score 2):

First, I'd consider using a `for-loop` as it'll manage the `i` value for you, but also consider the logic you have

```
if element.equals(userName) {...} 
else if !element.equals(userName) {...} 
else {...}
```

How is it possible to ever get into the `else` block, either `element` will be or won't be equal to the `userName`, there is no other state.  I'd consider having a flag which indicates if a user was found or not and checking that at the other end of the loop

As a general concept...

```
//...
userName = input.nextLine();

String validUser = null;
for (int index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    if (array[i].equals(userName)) {
        validUser = userName;
        break;
    }
}
if (validUser != null) {
    System.out.println("UserName is valid");
} else {
    System.out.println("Your UserName is not valid");
}
```

Because you probably don't care about the index so much, you can also do something like...

```
for (String element : array) {
    if (array[i].equals(userName)) {
        validUser = userName;
        break;
    }
}
```

which is shorthand version.

Have a look at [The for statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use a for loop but I kept getting stuck inside of it.

Comment: I wonder why this answer would attract a downvote? Are we not meant to help people anymore?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your **if** and **else if** are the only condition the java will run in your context and there are no other condition running afterwards. It is like you are doing TRUE and FALSE and expecting another condition. Make use of foreach in java much simpler way.

```
boolean found = false;
for(String name: array){
    if (name.equals(userName)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!found){
    System.out.println("Your UserName is not valid");
}else{
    System.out.println("Your UserName is valid");
}
```

When you get mastered use the methods of Array , Collections and specially lambdas stream api for little bit lift up your java knowledge.

Comment: I understand how this works but it's actually giving me the same error.

Comment: I wanna know what is the error that is coming in your side.

Answer (score 0):

Your Statement will never go to the `else` part, because the the input(`userName`) will either EQUAL `array[i]`, or not. Think about it...

```
if (array[i].equals(userName)) { //It will do this if userName is array[i]
    System.out.println("Your UserName is valid");
    break;
}
else if (!array[i].equals(userName)) { //It will do this if userName is NOT array[i]
    i++;
}

else { //this is impossible, unreachable code
    System.out.println("Your UserName is not valid");
    break;
}
```

The reason your `else` is not reachable is because it is an impossible scenario. I edited your program, and it works now. Here's the whole thing:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Experiments {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String userName;
        boolean found = false;

        String[] array = new String[3];
        array[0] = "John";
        array[1] = "Johny";
        array[2] = "ben";


        System.out.println("Enter your user name:");
        userName = input.nextLine();

        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
            if (userName.equalsIgnoreCase(array[i])) { 
                System.out.println("Your UserName is valid");
                found = true;
                break;
            }
            if (!found && i == array.length-1) {
                System.out.println("Your UserName is not valid");
            }
        }
        input.close();
    } 
}
```

If the input (userName) is in the array at any spot, it will say `"Your UserName is valid"` If it isn't in the array, it will say `"Your UserName is not valid"`.

Here is an example of a valid userName:

```
Enter your user name:
John
Your UserName is valid
```

And if the UserName is invalid:

```
Enter your user name:
Jimmy
Your UserName is not valid
```

Please comment if you have any questions about this, and I will explain.

Comment: Doesn't this make it say "your user name is not valid" no matter what the for loop is doing?

Comment: @Vezro - no, if the input (`userName`) is in the array at any spot, it will say `"Your UserName is valid`"

Comment: @Vezro is this answer acceptable? please let me know what I can improve, or what difficulties you're having. Thank you very much!